# How can i create a nested json in pandas from a dataframe using one column value as key?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have a dataframe df like below:

```
col1 | col2| col3| col4| col5
_____|_____|_____|_____|______
 1   |  X  |  A  |  a  |  x
 1   |  X  |  B  |  b  |  y
```

I need to convert it as below:

```
{'col1':'1', 'col2':'X' , 'A':{ 'col4':'a', 'col5':'x'}, 'B':{'col4':'b', 'col5':'y'}}
```

I have tried with below code:

```
json= df.groupby(['col1,'col2'],as_index='False')[['col3','col4','col5']]
                   .apply(lambda x:x.set_index('col3').to_dict(orient='index'))
                   .reset_index()
                   .to_json(orient='records'))
```

And it gives me output:

```
[{'col1':'1', 'col2':'X' ,'0':{ 'A':{ 'col4':'a', 'col5':'x'}, 'B':{'col4':'b', 'col5':'y'} }}]
```

I have tried using `to_dict` in place of `to_json` but it does not work as well. Above is the closest I came to meeting my requirement. I am assuming the '0' represents the index. Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: What do you want to remove?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
json= (df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],as_index='False')[['col4','col5']]
                   .apply(lambda x: dict(x.values))
                   .unstack()
                   .reset_index()
                   .to_json(orient='records')
)
print (json)
[{"col1":1,"col2":"X","A":{"a":"x"},"B":{"b":"y"}}]
```